# jQuery .load page without extension

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, get

**Is it possible to .get or .load from a page without php/html extension?** I meant the following:

I have this URL domain.com/page/3 and I want to get the contents of this page displayed on some other page.

I use

```
$('#div').load('/page/3');
```

But it doesn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks

---

**UPD:**
The problem is solved using load of exact portion of the page. It worked with the following:

```
$('#div').load('/page/3 #container');
```

Comment: Syntax is good. Do you have a element with `id='div'`? Try using a debugger like firebug to see if the http request was made.

Comment: try using absolute url's .. what you want is possible though.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ you can even load a portion of the page.... probably a bad reference as what Asterix93 said?

Comment: Yep, I have that #div set up on the page. I've also tried to use full URL. When the page is loaded it becomes blank. Console shows the requested get url for a second and then all is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (expecting your folder "page" exists, with a document called "3" inside) :

```
$('#div').load('page/3');
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the basis is for believing that a document relative URL will work where a root relative URL doesn't.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved using load of exact portion of the page. It worked with the following:

$('#div').load('/page/3 #container');